# How to add splash screen window correctly in MahApps.Metro application?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, splash-screen, mahapps.metro

I have added a splash screen window to a mahapps metro application with a progress ring. The splash screen is shown and closed before the main window is shown using the following code.

```
protected async override void OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //Other code

        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

        SplashScreen sp = new SplashScreen();
        sp.Show();
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        sp.Close();

        mainWindow.Show();

        //Other code
    }
```

Splash screen is shown correctly but the main window’s RightWindowCommands and LeftWindowCommands are not working correctly. Styles and data binding of WindowCommands are not working. For example, a button icon on the left is not visible and a button icon on right is visible but data binding is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2635